# Exception thrown in queued task- Helper returns correct value but throws error- Meteor

Tags: meteor

Fix this Error which is thrown in console on this page: http://salestrack.meteor.com/demos/overview:

```
Exception in queued task: TypeError: Cannot read property 'emails' of undefined at         Object.Template.demoOverviewItem.helpers.ownerRep       (http://localhost:3000/client/views/overviews/demo_overview_item.js?
```

Here is the helper they're referring to:

```
ownerRep: function(){
var rep = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}); 
var repEmail = rep.emails[0].address, 
repArr = [], 
repArr = repEmail.split('@'); 
return repArr[0]; 
}
});
```

The query is inserted into an inclusion block that loops over #each demos and looks up this.userId from the demos collection and matches it up to the user to return the owner of the demo's name.

Here are the templates that:

```
    <template name="demosOverview">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row-fluid col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-1">

    <table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered dataTable" id="editable-    sample">
    <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Rep</th>
        <th>SFID</th>
        <th>Date Set</th>
        <th>Closed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
     <tbody>
      {{#each demos}}
         {{> demoOverviewItem}}
      {{/each}}
     </tbody>

        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
</template>


<template name="demoOverviewItem">
 <tr>
    <td>{{ownerRep}}</td>
    <td> <a href="{{pathFor 'demoPage'}}">{{sfid}}</a> 

    <a href="{{sfid}}" class="pull-right" target="blank" title="Salesforce">
    <img src="/img/salesforce-logo.png" height="16" width="16">
    </a>

    </td>
    <td>{{dateset}}</td>
    <td>{{closed}}</td>
 </tr>
</template>
```

I am pub/subbing Meteor.users.find() from the server to the client but haven't paired it down to only send over certain fields yet (for easy hacking purposes).

Weird thing is that it works correctly and returns the demo owner's email address as expected. The error gets thrown when I reload the page but not when I navigate to it from elsewhere on the site.

Seems like a wait.On error or something where when I hit reload it doesn't know that currentUser = true so it throws the error before realizing I'm logged in- that's just a theory though. I've googled, StackOv and IRCed to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like on page reload you don't have the users on the client side yet.
Try

```
var rep = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId}); 
if (rep) {
var repEmail = rep.emails[0].address, (..) 
}
```

It should rerun once findOne has the data it's looking for.

Comment: Glad I was able to help! Please go ahead and accept my answer. :) Thanks!